# How to handle apollo client errors crashing page render in Nuxt?

Tags: vue.js, error-handling, graphql, nuxt.js, apollo

I'm currently maintaining a production Nuxt.js Vue app that integrates GraphQL Apollo Client that's running into page render errors. For the sake of boosting my chances of getting a response, I built a bare-bones code example that showcases only the problem we are running into. Thanks everybody.

**Source Code**

- Client, https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/error-apollo-client-nuxt
- Server, https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/error-apollo-server

**The Problem**

The problem, is that every now and then, the GraphQL server we rely on (we have no control over it) goes down and returns a HTML error page, which crashes Apollo Client due to its attempt to parse the GraphQL spec JSON response. This yields the infamous `Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0` error that's been reported [over](https://github.com/apollographql/apollo-feature-requests/issues/153) and [over](https://github.com/graphql-boilerplates/node-graphql-server/issues/274) again.

The thing is, because we are using the `@nuxt/apollo` Nuxt module that integrates Apollo into the render pipeline, this makes Nuxt's page render crash. Giving us a generic server render error page that looks like this;

[image: Nuxt server error page]

```
 ERROR  Network error: Unexpected token < in JSON at position 0                                                            08:11:04

  at new ApolloError (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:92:26)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1588:34
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2008:15
  at Set.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2006:26
  at Map.forEach (<anonymous>)
  at QueryManager.broadcastQueries (node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:2004:20)
  at node_modules/apollo-client/bundle.umd.js:1483:29
  at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:94:5)
```

**How to reproduce the error**

Clone the repositories from above, and start both of them following the readme.md commands. (for the server error, make sure to run `npm run start-express` since that's the one that crashes the client).

You'll notice the [pages/index.js](https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/error-apollo-client-nuxt/blob/master/pages/index.vue#L34) throws a server error page since the server returns an invalid HTML response.

**What we tried**

We tried following every error handling spec in the Vue Apollo and Nuxt apollo docs, but nothing seems to work. We tried:

- Adding the Nuxt "@apollo/nuxt" module [supported error handler syntax](https://github.com/nuxt-community/apollo-module/blob/master/README.md#errorhandler-example). It gets logged correctly, but the error doesn't stop propagating and crashes the page render. Even if we [return false at the end](https://github.com/sgarcia-dev/error-apollo-client-nuxt/blob/master/apollo/onError.js#L30). Which we thought that would, since that's what the source code for [vue-apollo seems to do](https://github.com/vuejs/vue-apollo/blob/83fb002c39519be0eeadad148d6ec58c552d4cc1/packages/vue-apollo/src/smart-apollo.js#L151-L195)
- Setting an apollo client [errorPolicy](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/react/data/error-handling/#error-policies) of `ignore` and `all`, but the error still got through and crashed the page render
- Adding individual query `error()` handlers and not relying on the global one. They stopped propagation to the global page, but it didn't stop the page render error from happening.
- Using `apollo-link-error`'s approach to [ignoring errors](https://www.apollographql.com/docs/link/links/error/#ignoring-errors) by adding a `link` property to our nuxt apollo config and following those steps. The link configuration ran, and errors were indeed logged. But `response` in that example evaluates to undefined, stopping us from being able to do `response.error`. I assume its a Nuxt compatibility issue thing being SSR and all, and that this might be designed for React applications.

**Summary**

Even simple pages using nuxt/apollo module crash page render on an invalid GraphQL response, and we have no idea how to stop it from happening other than migrating our app from using nuxt/apollo and instead using apollo client directly which will be quite expensive.... any ideas?

Comment: Thanks for the detailed desc, currently trying to plan for similar cases. May I ask what you ended up doing ?

Comment: We decided to move away from the Vue Apollo smart query implementation since we deemed we wasted too much time trying to fix it from Nuxt.js 's side and its poor documentation/community support. So we just ended up doing apollo queries using promises in a vue component hook, but plan to move away from Nuxt.js in the future.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. May I ask why move away from nuxt and towards what?

Comment: Did you try https://github.com/Gomah/nuxt-graphql-request ?

Comment: No, I think we didn't try that plugin. But if we heard about it, we probably wouldn't have used it since it's not very popular or active and we had ran into enough issues using low adoption tools with unfixed bugs and missing docs. BTW, I looked into it and the implementation using asyncData and promises is almost exactly what we did using the nuxt Apollo plug-in. Oh, and our road map was to move away from Nuxt and just use vanilla Vue.js

Comment: Maybe this would be useful .. wondering if I can be used in nuxt as well.
https://apolloelements.dev

Answer (score 0):

Wouldn't it be possible to run your apollo queries through a computed property (which is displayed in the template). That way, you could check in the computed property for JSON errors and catch them there before making them available to the template render process.

Comment: Yup, but if we're doing that, I think you might as well process them under the fetch hook to let them run in SSR mode, while still having control over the fail state using promises.